# Query Posts by Tag and exclude

Tags: wp-query, tags

Is it possible to only include posts with a specific tag in this query?

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query
            (array('showposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'));
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
```

Also is there also a way to exclude posts with a certain tag as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the [`tag` parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tag' => 'YOUR-TAG-SLUG',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();

    ...

endwhile;
// don't forget to reset/restore the query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: It ended up being `tag` and `tag_not_in`, but this put me in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I absolutely misinterpreted your question and thought you meant _parameter/argument_ when saying _tag_ - and not an actual post tag. I'll update my answer. Glad it pointed you in the right direction anyway.